# phpmyadmin error with mbstring func overload

Tags: php, utf-8, phpmyadmin

When I setted `mbstring.func_overload=7` PHPMyAdmin now shows an error at starting. (phpmyadmin incompatibile with func_overload)

I mandatory need `func_overload = 7`... Is there any patch or workaround to get it working with phpmyadmin?

Comment: What is the issue you are trying to solve? What inside phpMyAdmin is not working?

Comment: phnpmyadmin says: "phpmyadmin is incompatible with mbstring.func_overload, your data could become corrupted". ATM it's working normally

Comment: I mean what issue are you trying to solve with `mbstring.func_overload=7`?

Comment: I need it because the framework we use doens't use mbstring where it should

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your server configuration, you may be able to override the php.ini setting for your phpMyAdmin directory.

See these question for approaches:  [Overriding global php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781927/overriding-global-php-ini-file) and  ['Overwrite' php.ini settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899326/overwrite-php-ini-settings)

Comment: I can put an .htaccess there... Should I create an .htaccess with just this? `php_value mbstring.func_overload 0` ? Edit: did this and now for that dir apache returns 500 internal server error :(

Comment: @yes then PHP may not be running as an Apache module, in which case that is not possible... If you're using PHP 5.3, you can use  http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: Yes i have php 5.3, I have created a php.ini in the phpmyadmin dir with just: `[mbstring]
mbstring.func_overload = 0` and restarted apache, but still phpmyadmin shows that warning

Comment: @yes I think the file needs to be named `.user.ini`

Comment: renamed it, restarted apache, still warning. on the official page php says "these files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI. " dunno if i have that

Comment: @yes then I don't know how to fix it - I have no experience with per-user INI files, sorry

Comment: doh.. I have even decommented "user_ini.filename = .user.ini" setting in my php.ini and restarted apache but still it seems it doesnt' get readed the file .user.ini. I have also did a phpinfo(); to see if the settings was taken and yes there the right setting =/ @pekka

Comment: Well the only solution I see is to refactor all my framework to using mb_* when needed, and remove the func_overload :( This will take some time